# Can't access router from the internet

Tags: networking, router

I was trying to connect to my raspberry pi via ssh from a remote location, and I noticed that even though I did the port forwarding correctly, I couldn't connect. So I tried everything I know, and I noticed that my public IP is not accessible from anywhere. I tried any port possible and it doesn't react to ping at all. Do you think something in my router is set incorrectly? Or did my ISP screw something up behind my back. I have a DSL connection

Here are my router's settings:

[image: WAN info]

[image: WAN settings]

Note: I've never had this issue before and port forwarding always worked

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a public IP address. That means your ISP is using [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). You cannot receive incoming connections this way. There is also no way for you to change this. Sorry!

You could try a different ISP, get a business subscription (they often even include a static IPv4 address) or perhaps just ask them to give you a public IP address.

Comment: wait, so they changed it recently? I've had the same ISP for 10 years and no one has informed me of this

Comment: Could be a recent change, yes. IPv4 addresses are scarce these days, yet more and more people want Internet access.

Comment: Well, I have no IPv6 address, so it looks like they've just ordered a tech support call :D Thanks for your time

Comment: According to the settings page, you do in fact have IPv6. You can easily confirm this on Linux too, using `ip -6 addr`.

Comment: @FilipHavlíček This is actually becoming more common all around the world, and don't expect support to help because most ISPs have had it then ToS for residential customers that incoming connections and/or public IPs are not supported with this service even though they often worked before. You now need to pay for a static public IP address, which can very from a few dollars to as much as $50 per month depending on ISP, and without one traffic is not routable to you.

Comment: Wait, so I need a static IP address now? I didn't really care that it changed from time to time... Well that sucks

Comment: No, you don’t. But why would they offer a dynamic IPv4 address when they can carge more for a static address? Granted, I wouldn’t pay extra for a dynamic address at all.